Why does the group by order matter in SQL Server?
I was doing some SELECT queries in SQL Server and noticed that the order of the GROUP BY makes it run about 6x faster.
The PAGOS table has more than 900,000 rows, the CXC table has 160,000 rows, and the CLIENTES table has 12,000 rows.
This query takes 18 seconds:
SELECT C.CLAVE 
FROM CLIENTES C
JOIN CXC ON CXC.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
LEFT JOIN PAGOS P ON P.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
WHERE P.CLIENTE IS NULL
GROUP BY P.CLIENTE, C.CLAVE

This query takes 3 seconds:
SELECT C.CLAVE 
FROM CLIENTES C
JOIN CXC ON CXC.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
LEFT JOIN PAGOS P ON P.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
WHERE P.CLIENTE IS NULL
GROUP BY C.CLAVE, P.CLIENTE

My question is, why does this happen?
I researched this, but many sources mention that the order doesn't matter. Why does it matter in my case?
Edit:
I forget to comment that if I don't group by the P.Cliente the query takes 18s, the same as GROUP BY P.CLIENTE, C.CLAVE
ACTUAL EXECUTION PLANS
GROUP BY P.CLIENTE,C.CLAVE
GROUP BY C.CLAVE,P.CLIENTE
IMAGES EXECUTION PLANS
c.clave,p.cliente
p.cliente,c.clave

Have you compared the query plans?

I must admit, however, that query looks odd. Why are you using a GROUP BY at all when there's no aggregation? Why have P.CLIENTE in the GROUP BY at all, when it isn't in the SELECT, and can only have the value NULL?

You might have a drastic difference in Cliente groups as compared to Clave groups

Are you sure you want to run this query? Why do you want to group by p.cliente since it's always null by definition? P.CLIENTE IS NULL

Honestly, that query looks like it would be better written with EXISTS: SELECT C.CLAVE FROM dbo.CLIENTES C WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CXC WHERE CXC.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PAGOS P WHERE P.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE); If C.CLAVE isn't unique, then pop a DISTINCT in there.

I only want the clients that are in the CXC table and not in the PAGOS table, that's why I do that

The query plan is the same for the two queries

"The query plan is the same for the two queries" then more likely when you ran the first query either there was a blocking process, or the data is now cached so running it a second time was significantly quicker.

I tried your query, it have a execution time of 8s

I tried running repeately, it's the same, 18s and 3s of execution time

@user25575372 there's no reason to group by P.CLIENTE no matter what you want. What are the actual execution plans? That's what really matters. I suspect SQL Server eliminates grouping by P.CLIENTE because it knows it will always be NULL. Post the execution plans in the query itself. Also check Does your GROUP BY Order matter?. Which SQL Server version are you using, and which columns are indexed ?

Then the query plans differ. Can you Paste the Plans?

I tried running repeatedly it doesn't matter. What are the actual execution plans? That's what gets executed, not the query text

I'll add the execution plans, i'll edit my question

The query plan is the same for the two queries did you check the actual details or just the shape? If you check Brent Ozar's Does your GROUP BY Order matter? you'll see that the same operation (eg seek, scan, group) may work on different columns, resulting in different performance

Oh, thanks for the link!, i'll read it

I added the images.

My sql server version is 2022

Those are images... We can't inspect those.

I'm sorry for that, what can I send to make it clearer?

As I asked, Paste the Plans.

link GROUP BY P.CLIENTE,C.CLAVE
link GROUP BY C.CLAVE,P.CLIENTE

And use the [edit] feature...

I forget to comment that if I don't group by the P.Cliente the query takes 18s

Can you paste the actual execution plan XML (not estimated plans) for an 18 second execution and a 3 second execution? The actual plans have timing information  that will tell you where the time was spent

I added the actual execution plan, I'm sorry for not including before, is my first time asking

This is a good question: the only difference I can see in the plans is the extra latch wait times. Possibly the prefetch for the parallelized reads is getting itself in a twist.

24 comments... welcome to support.stackoverflow.com...

To be really honest, the real issue isn't why the slow plan isn't as fast as the fast plan. They are both terribly slow. You have here parallel scans and merge joins of three enormous tables, but the final Filter is only outputting 48 rows. So an enormous amount of effort for not very much.
If you remove P.CLIENTE from the GROUP BY entirely (given it's unnecessary), then it may be possible for the compiler to rearrange the plan to get the join on PAGOS first.
But that LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL should really be written as an anti-join using NOT EXISTS. The other join can also be written as a semi-join (given that you are grouping by the first table only) which might encourage the compiler to put the anti-join first.
SELECT
  C.CLAVE 
FROM CLIENTES C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM PAGOS P
    WHERE P.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CXC
    WHERE CXC.CLIENTE = C.CLAVE
)
GROUP BY
  C.CLAVE;

I would then expect the compiler to take an anti-join of CLIENTES and PAGOS first, either a Merge or a Nested Loop but the latter is probably better, and then do a Nested Loop of CXC. If it doesn't do that then it might need better encouragement. A fuller example with your table and index definitions would help for that.

Thank you for the comment!, looking at your query, I can notice what mine was missing, I learned a lot, thank you again for the observations!

The execution plan XML is identical for both queries.
The difference in performance looks to be down to whether or not data was in cache.
The fast plan (4.6 seconds) shows only one physical read whereas the slow one (28.3 seconds) shows

1396 phys reads from CLIENTES
444  phys reads from CXC
681 phys reads from PAGOS

This is still only a total of 2,521 physical reads though.
The wait stats in the slow plan are
        <WaitStats>
          <Wait WaitType="LATCH_EX" WaitTimeMs="390713" WaitCount="198" />
          <Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="267865" WaitCount="2788" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXPACKET" WaitTimeMs="261010" WaitCount="102" />
          <Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_EX" WaitTimeMs="4805" WaitCount="12" />
          <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="565" WaitCount="6334" />
          <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="182" WaitCount="51311" />
          <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="120" WaitCount="5328" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXSYNC_PORT" WaitTimeMs="55" WaitCount="85" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXSYNC_CONSUMER" WaitTimeMs="10" WaitCount="33" />
          <Wait WaitType="SESSION_WAIT_STATS_CHILDREN" WaitTimeMs="3" WaitCount="7" />
        </WaitStats>

and in the fast plan
        <WaitStats>
          <Wait WaitType="CXPACKET" WaitTimeMs="36325" WaitCount="109" />
          <Wait WaitType="LATCH_EX" WaitTimeMs="18090" WaitCount="159" />
          <Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="5388" WaitCount="55" />
          <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="743" WaitCount="8047" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXSYNC_PORT" WaitTimeMs="107" WaitCount="84" />
          <Wait WaitType="RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="70" WaitCount="5328" />
          <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="22" WaitCount="4221" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXROWSET_SYNC" WaitTimeMs="15" WaitCount="10" />
          <Wait WaitType="CXSYNC_CONSUMER" WaitTimeMs="11" WaitCount="33" />
          <Wait WaitType="CMEMTHREAD" WaitTimeMs="2" WaitCount="37" />
        </WaitStats>

The average wait for PAGEIOLATCH_SH was 100 ms so it looks like the IO is pretty slow and these waits for physical reads consequently have a large effect even in fairly low numbers.
I presume the LATCH_EX waits are a knock on effect from this as threads wait for the next range to scan from the parent dataset - though you should follow the advice here to see what the type of latch involved actually is.

Arguably the parallelization is unnecessary in the first place, given the small size of the first table.
